# OSGi test fragment dependencies with Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi, eclipse-rcp

If I understand correctly, the suggested way of white-box testing in OSGi is to add a (test) fragment to the bundle that needs to be tested. I have the following setup:

- Bundle 'com.bundleA' with package 'com.bundleA.foo'
- Fragment 'com.bundleA.tests' with package 'com.bundleA.foo' & 'com.bundleA.utils'
- Bundle 'com.bundleB' with package 'com.bundleB.bar'
- Fragment 'com.bundleB.tests' with package 'com.bundleB.bar'
- 'com.bundleA' exports 'com.bundleA.foo'
- 'com.bundleA.tests' exports 'com.bundleA.utils'
- 'com.bundleB' imports package 'com.bundleA.foo'

My use-case is as followed: I want 'com.bundleB.tests' to import 'com.bundleA.utils'. In OSGi, it doesn't matter where a package is exported from. Eclipse PDE however needs 'Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI=true' in 'com.bundleA' to make it understand that 'com.bundleA.tests' can export additional packages. However, at compile time 'com.bundleB' can now access classes from 'com.bundleA.foo' in the test fragment! This is undesired as the fragment won't be deployed so there will be run-time errors.

What are the best practices given this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use case: you want com.bundleB.tests to import com.bundleA.utils, but com.bundleA.utils is a fragment of com.bundleA. Creating fragments for unittests is ok, but not when parts of this fragments must be used by other unittests from other bundles.
You should create a bundle with only the utils classes which must be shared (com.bundleC) which is only used by the unittest fragments and which contain the com.bundleA.utils package.

Comment: Although I understand your answer, 'com.bundleC' would not be able to access non exported packages, while this is a necessity for my situation. In addition, if 'com.bundleA.tests' depends on 'com.bundleC' (which it will, since the testutils has been moved there), a cyclic dependency occurs. Making 'com.bundleC' a fragment will re-establish the problem of test-ware being accessible from production code.